# The normal cone to a ball at a boundary point of the ball

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-cone

I got stuck in a problem that in the end I needed to know what is the normal cone to a ball $B = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lVert x \rVert \leq 1 \right\}$ (here $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is an arbirtrary norm), at a point at the boundary $\partial B$. Recalling that the normal cone to a closed convex set $C$ at a point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set

$$N_C(x) = \left\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle y,z-x \rangle \leq 0 \ \forall z \in C \right\}.$$

I manage to compute it for $n = 1$, you can assume $B = [-1,1]$, if I'm not mistaken, it is

$$N_B(x) = \begin{cases} 
[0,+\infty), & \ \text{if} \ x=1, \\
(-\infty,0], & \ \text{if} \ x=-1.\end{cases}$$

Intuitively, I think the normal cone $N_B(x)$ will always be a half space at boundary points, but I don't know how this in a more general setting, is my intuition correct? If not, what is it? Any help, hints or references would be appreciated.

$\textbf{Edit}:$ Actually when the norm is differentiable at the point I managed to see that the normal cone is a line (using e.g. Theorem 23.7 of Rockafellar's Convex Analysis book), so the problem actually lies in points where the norm is not differentiable.

Comment: Ny unchecked geometric intuition suggests the following. If at $x$ there is a tangent hyperplane to $B$ then $N_B(x)$ consists of the ray from the origin of $\mathbb R^n$ orthogonal to that hyperplane. Otherwise $N_B(x)$ can be bigger. For instance, if $\mathbb R^2$ is endowed with the $\ell_\infty$ norm then at $x=(1,1)$ we have $N_B(x)=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb R^2: x_1,x_2\ge 0\}$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I forgot to edit, but I actually manage to do it for $C^1$ norms, the problem really is for these points where the cone can be bigger (where the norm is non differentiable), to me it seems it is going to be "really" big, like, having $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (like in the points where the $l_{\infty}$ norm is not differentiable), do you know if it can be smaller than this?

Comment: I don't think these discussions about different norms make sense. The definition of the cone uses an inner product, and that would mean we are using the standard Euclidean inner product and $\ell^2$ norm on ${\mathbb R}^n$. Then the normal cone to the ball at a boundary point is a half-space.

Comment: Also, in your example for $n=1$, I think the cones point in the other directions. Just check it with your definition.

Comment: @Threeaggies yes, the directions were wrong, thanks, just edited it, and the thing about looking at other norms is because you can think of normal cones with respect to any closed convex set and balls are convex, the fact that they are defined with inner product does not affect that

Comment: The same intuition suggests that the cone can have less that $n$ linearly vectors, for instance, when the norm is a product of norms, for instance, consider the norm $\|\cdot\|_2\times \|\cdot\|_1$ on $\mathbb R^3$. Then for any angle $\varphi$, $x=(\cos\varphi,\sin\varphi,1)\in \partial B$ the cone $N_B(x)$ is spanned by two independent vectors $(\sin\varphi,-\cos\varphi,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Given $x, y$, $$H(x,y) = \{ z\ :\ y\cdot(z-x) \le 0 \}$$ is the half-space whose boundary contains $x$ and is normal to $y$. Therefore, $y \in N_C(x)$ if $C \subset H(x,y)$. If $\partial C$ is differentiable at $x$, then $y$ is normal to the tangent plane to $\partial C$ at $x$. In that case, $N_C(x)$ is a half-line. It is in fact the case (as proved in Rockafellar) that $\partial C$ is differentiable at $x$ if and only if $N_C(x)$ is a half-line. At a non-differentiable point, $N_C(x)$ is a convex cone containing more than one half-line.

Comment: @AlexRavsky what do you mean by this product of norms?

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta Oops, sorry. I meant $\|(x,y,z)\|=\max\{\sqrt{x^2+y^2},|z|\}$ for each $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Now I see, I think you meant $(\cos{\varphi},\sin{\varphi},0)$ instead of $(\sin{\varphi},-\cos{\varphi},0)$, but still, is spanned by just two vectors and not three

Comment: Right, sorry for the error and thanks for your correction.

Comment: Maybe given any nonzero $x\in\mathbb R^n$, any convex closed cone $C\ni 0$ with nonempty interior such that $0\not\in x+C$ can be obtained as $C=N_B(x)$ for the unit ball $B$ of some Minkowski norm. Maybe, for $B=(x-C^*)\cap (C^*-x)$, where $C^*=\{z\in\mathbb R^n:\langle y,z\rangle\le 0\,\forall y\in C\}$

Comment: Can I have your feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|\cdot\|_*$ denote the dual norm to $\|\cdot\|$:
$$
\|y\|_* := \sup_{\|x\|\le 1} x^Ty.
$$
This implies
$$
x^Ty \le \|x\| \cdot \|y\|_*.
$$
Let
$$
B:=\{x: \ \|x\|\le 1\}.
$$

---

**Claim**.
The normal cone of the  unit ball $B$ is then
$$
N_B(x) = \{ y: \ x^Ty = \|y\|_*\}.
$$

---

*Proof*.
Assume $x^Ty = \|y\|_*$. Take $z\in B$. Then
$$
\langle y,z-x \rangle \le \|y\|_* \|z\| - \|y\|_* \le 0.
$$
Now take $y \in N_B(x) $. By compactness, there is $z$ with $\|z\|\le 1$ such that $z^Ty=\|y\|_*$. Then
$$
0 \ge \langle y, z-x \rangle = \|y\|_* - y^Tx,
$$
which implies $y^Tx \ge \|y\|_*$.
Since $\|x\|=1$,  this implies $x^Ty = \|y\|_*$ by
$$
\|y\|_* \le x^Ty \le \|x\|\cdot \|y\|_* = \|y\|_*.
$$

Comment: This result actually follow directly from the Theorem I mentioned in the post and the characterization of the subdifferential of a norm, I wanted a more precise description (possibly involving dimension of the cone, or if it has a non-empty interior if the point is not differentiable), but from the comments I think that this may not be possible

Answer (score 1):

My answer is

$$ N_B(x) = \textbf{cone} (\partial \, \|x\|), \tag{1}$$

which is the conical hull of the subdifferential of $\|x\|$.

By definition, for sub-gradient $y \in \partial \, \|x\|$, for any $z$ the following holds:

$$y^T(z-x) \le \|z\|-\|x\|.$$

By considering the points $x$ and $z$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $\|z\|=1$, we obtain

$$y^T(z-x) \le 0.$$

If $y$ satisfies the above, so does $\lambda y$ for any $\lambda \ge 0$, which gives the result (1).

When $\|x\|$ is differentiable at $x$, i.e., $$\partial \, \|x\|=\{ \nabla \|x\| \},$$ $N_B(x)$ is a ray from $0$ along the gradient $\nabla \|x\|$.

For $n=1$, the gradients (derivatives) of $|x|$ at $x=-1$ and $x=1$ are $-1$ and $1$, respectively, so from (1) we obtain

$$N_B(x) = \begin{cases} 
[0,+\infty), & \ \text{if} \ x=1, \\
(-\infty,0], & \ \text{if} \ x=-1.\end{cases}$$

For $n=2$ and $\|x\|=\|x\|_1$, from (1) the normal cone at point $x=\left (\frac 12,\frac 12 \right)^T$ is given by

$$\left \{\lambda \binom 11, \lambda \ge0  \right \},$$

while at point $x=(1,0)^T$, it becomes

$$\left \{\lambda _1\binom 11+\lambda _2\binom {1}{-1}, \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \ge0  \right \}.$$

Comment: I think I did not explain what I wanted very clearly, in fact, I was studying the normal cone to try to understand better the subdifferential of a norm in the points where it is not differentiable, but it seems to not have a simple answer, thanks for your help